# How to induce native ListView scrolling [android]

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

I have a problem with my `ListView` after I have overriden `onInterceptTouchEvent` in my parent view. The `ListView` just won't scroll.

I've tried dispatching `MotionEvent` to the `ListView` but it doesn't seem to be handled in any way.

```
boolean done = mListView.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
Log.d("listView dispatch", String.valueOf(done));
```

`done` is always true, so I guess the event is received correctly.

I've also tried scrolling the `ListView` by offset and by position but these produced a very artificial experience.

Is there a way to get my `ListView` to scroll in the default way?